# Computing the norm of the columns of an implicitly defined matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an $n \times n$ matrix $M = \Sigma W$ where $\Sigma$ is diagonal and $W$ orthogonal. $W$ is implicitly defined, i.e. I can only perform matrix-vector products (but I also have access to $W^T$).

I need to compute the norms $\|M^i\|$ of the columns of $M$ so that I can use them to find an upper bound on $\|Mx\|$ for a given vector $x$.

Of course I can compute $\|M e_i\|$ for all $i$, but this would require $n$ matrix-vector products.

An alternative would be to compute the diagonal of $M^T M = W^T \Sigma^2 W$. I found [this paper](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2005-082.pdf) which shows how to estimate the diagonal of a matrix using only a small number of matrix-vector products with random vectors, but it is still in the order of hundreds, if not worse (and the result is approximate).

Is there a way to exploit the structure of my matrix to obtain a more efficient solution?

Comment: Do you actually have $\Sigma$?

Comment: You want to compute $n$ quantities $\|M^i\|$, and you can only perform matrix-vector products. Would this mean, in principle, you cannot reduce the work significantly?

Comment: @felix yes, $\Sigma$ is explicit

Comment: So, if $y=Wx$ (which is available), then $Mx=\Sigma y$ and you can estimate $Mx$ directly.

Too simple, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Ciao Giuseppe! Can you be more specific on the kind of bound that you are looking for? It can't be a bound of the kind  $\leq C\left\Vert x \right\Vert$, otherwise you can forget about the orthogonal $W$ and focus on $\Sigma$ only. Right?

Comment: Ciao Federico! I didn't know you were here :)
$\leq C\|x\|$ would be too loose, I basically need to estimate the "influence" of each coordinate on $\|M x\|$, to see which ones I can change without changing too much the norm of the product. 
The idea would be to bound $\|M x\|$ with $(\|M^1\| \dots \|M^n\|)^T \cdot |x|$, using the triangle inequality.


Comment: @Felix of course I can compute $\|Mx\|$ exactly, but if I change a coordinate in $x$ I have to recompute the product, which is expensive. So I want to bound the norm of the product with the norms of the columns.